# How to do Pagination in ASP.NET MVC using Sql Data Adapter

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This is the error while doing pagination. While applying skip to obj getting this error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Sample.SchedularTask.Models.ScheduleDapper>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Sample.SchedularTask.Models.ScheduleDapper>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)   Sample.SchedularTask    E:\Downloads\CINCAI\CINCAI_SampleMT\Sample.SchedularTask\Controllers\HomeController.cs  59  Active

```
    public async Task<IActionResult>  Index(int PageNumber=1)
    {         
        List<ScheduleDapper> obj=   ScheduleDapper.GetAllSchedule();

        for (int i = 0; i < obj.Count; i++)
        {
            var enumDisplayStatus = (StatusEnum)obj[i].Status;
            string stringValue = enumDisplayStatus.ToString();
            obj[i].Statusvalue = stringValue;
        }
        var users = obj.ToList();
        ViewBag.TotalPages =Math.Ceiling( obj.Count() / 1.0);
        users=users.Skip((PageNumber-1)*10);
        
        return View(obj);
```

Comment: Please show your pagination code, as formatted text, not as a screenshot (which no one can read). You'll also need to show your model and database table definitions - all as formatted text.

Comment: The error says "An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" - have you tried adding the suggested cast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The users variable is declared as List here -

```
var users = obj.ToList();
```

And again while applying skip IEnumerable is assigned back (Skip will result in IEnumerable), hence the casting error -

```
users=users.Skip((PageNumber-1)*10);
```

If you want list, may be just evaluate the result to List as below -

```
users=users.Skip((PageNumber-1)*10).ToList();
```